# I want to store data from database in a local storage

Tags: database, android-studio, local-storage

I have coded this app that onClicklistener fetch data from the database and store them in fragments that are displayed in a frame layout on the main activity, Now I want the data to be stored in a device permanently in order to be not fetched every time the button with onclicklistener is clicked.

Sorry I am new to this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
localStorage.setItem('keyname', itemtostore)
```

But this is to simple. We need to know that type of data you want store, to do the right treatment